# How to determine what to import for, for example, the matchFlags used with QTreeWidget.findItems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to use function QTreeWidget.findItems to find an exact match (the item is named "Things")
I saw an example using this ... Qt.MatchExactly  ... as the 'match flag'.
even though i had imported Qt module from PyQt5, the MatchExactly was not found.
I got it to work by importing ANOTHER Qt module found in QtCore in PyQt5.  but that was after many hours over several days of poking, guessing, and reading stackOverFlow posts.

My question is - how to know what module contains (and therefore must be imported) the stuff I need?  how would I know that Qt.MatchExactly is in the PyQt5.QtCore.Qt module (and NOT in PyQt5.Qt module)?

This is my code: Note it reads in a QtDesigner .ui file, so its not gonna work for you.  but having you run this code is not the point.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTreeWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, Qt #<<flags are not here
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt #<<<this is where i found the match flag "MatchExactly"

qtCreatorFile = "Main2.ui" # Enter qt Designer file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)       

        self.InitModelContentTree()

    def InitModelContentTree (self):
        modelContentTree = self.ui.ModelContentTree
        ThingsItemList = modelContentTree.findItems("Things", Qt.MatchExactly)
        ThingsItem = ThingsItemList[0]
        QTreeWidgetItem(ThingsItem, ["New Thing"])
        print("pause")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i'm hoping there is a decoder ring, some basic thing i'm missing.  i'm proving to be a very bad, very inefficient guesser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Qt.MatchExactly is in Qt but you must import it in another way:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

# ...

ThingsItemList = modelContentTree.findItems("Things", Qt.Qt.MatchExactly)
```

**TL; DR**

The Qt submodule is a fake module that allows access to any module such as an alias, for example it is similar to:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore as Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui as Qt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as Qt
# ...
# The same for all submodules
```

For example it can be checked for Qt.MatchExactly:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore

assert(QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly == Qt.Qt.MatchExactly)
```

So in general the following import:

```
from PyQt5 import somemodule

somemodule.someclass
```

It is equivalent to:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

Qt.someclass
```

**How to know what submodule a class belongs to?**: Well, if you have an IDE that can do a self-report like pycharm, the task is simple since the IDE itself does it. But if I do not have access to the IDE the other option is to use the docs of Qt, for example the docs of [Qt::MatchExactly](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt.html) is in this link that in the first part is the following table:

[image]

And observe `Qt += core` so all the elements of that docs belong to the core sub-module of Qt that in PyQt/PySide corresponds to QtCore (in general if the docs of Qt indicate `Qt += mymodule` in PyQt/PySide in `QtMyModule`).Also the `Qt::MatchExactly` of C ++ corresponds to `Qt.MatchExactly` in python. So in conclusion you should use:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly
```